Predict next word in sentence
First I was getting this : Error in base::colMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...): 'x' must be numeric . So changed prefix_embedding as a numeric matrix before passing it to colMeans()
Then I added added  as.numeric function so that each element in prefix_embedding is numeric before taking the transpose and calculating the column means.
Then replaced non-existent words with the special token "UNKNOWN". Then, during the embedding lookup, handled this special token separately.
Then added step to convert all words to lowercase before checking if they are present in the embeddings model.
Now I am Getting : Error in predict_next_option_word_embeddings(words, embeddings_model, : NA values detected in prefix_embedding.
`library(textTinyR)

load_glove_embeddings <- function(file_path) {
  embeddings <- readLines(file_path)
  word_embeddings <- lapply(embeddings, function(line) {
    tokens <- strsplit(line, "\\s+")[[1]]
    word <- tokens[1]
    embedding <- as.numeric(tokens[-1])
    return(list(word = word, embedding = embedding))
  })
  names(embeddings) <- sapply(word_embeddings, function(emb) emb$word)
  return(embeddings)
}

preprocess_text <- function(text) {
  text <- tolower(text)
  # Remove punctuation
  text <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", text)
  # Tokenize words
  words <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\\s+"))
  return(words)
}

cosine_similarity <- function(x, y) {
  dot_product <- sum(x * y)
  norm_x <- sqrt(sum(x^2))
  norm_y <- sqrt(sum(y^2))
  return(dot_product / (norm_x * norm_y))
}

predict_next_option_word_embeddings <- function(prefix, embeddings_model, options) {
  prefix_embedding <- sapply(prefix, function(word) {
    word <- tolower(word)  # Convert word to lowercase
    if (word %in% names(embeddings_model)) {
      return(embeddings_model[[word]])
    } else {
      # Use zero vector for out-of-vocabulary words
      return(rep(0, length(embeddings_model[[1]])))
    }
  })
  
  prefix_embedding <- t(sapply(prefix_embedding, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))))
  
  if (any(is.na(prefix_embedding))) {
    print("NA values detected in prefix_embedding:")
    print(prefix)
    print(prefix_embedding)
    stop("NA values detected in prefix_embedding.")
  }
  
  if (any(!is.numeric(prefix_embedding))) {
    stop("Non-numeric values detected in prefix_embedding.")
  }
  
  prefix_embedding <- colMeans(prefix_embedding)
  
  option_similarities <- sapply(options, function(opt) {
    if (opt %in% names(embeddings_model)) {
      option_embedding <- embeddings_model[[opt]]
      
      if (any(!is.numeric(option_embedding))) {
        stop("Non-numeric values detected in option_embedding for option: ", opt)
      }
      
      return(cosine_similarity(prefix_embedding, option_embedding))
    } else {
      return(0)
    }
  })
  
  predicted_option <- options[which.max(option_similarities)]
  return(predicted_option)
}


  
glove_file <- "/kaggle/input/glove-embeddings/glove.6B.50d.txt"  
embeddings_model <- load_glove_embeddings(glove_file)

# User input: Sentence
sentence <- readline("Enter the sentence: ")

# User input: Options
options_str <- readline("Enter the options (comma-separated): ")
options <- unlist(strsplit(options_str, ","))

words <- preprocess_text(sentence)

next_option <- predict_next_option_word_embeddings(words, embeddings_model, options)
next_option`


First I was getting this : Error in base::colMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...): 'x' must be numeric . So changed prefix_embedding as a numeric matrix before passing it to colMeans()
Then I added added  as.numeric function so that each element in prefix_embedding is numeric before taking the transpose and calculating the column means.
Then replaced non-existent words with the special token "UNKNOWN". Then, during the embedding lookup, handled this special token separately.
Then added step to convert all words to lowercase before checking if they are present in the embeddings model.
Now I am Getting : Error in predict_next_option_word_embeddings(words, embeddings_model, : NA values detected in prefix_embedding.
What I want a model which can predict next word in the sentence from available options

Hi vinit. Please see this post. https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example It's difficult to follow what you wrote. Start with what you are trying to do, then include more detailed steps if necessary.
